# Website construction help

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to build a website. At a particular time, daily, say 6pm, a scheduled task runs. How should i say, "pause" users who are viewing my site, and show them the progress of the scheduled task that is being executed, say in the form of a jquery ui progress bar, like "task starting", "task executing", "task terminating"...

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to communicate the status at all, or how to make the animated jQuery part?

Comment: @deceze: I need to know how to communicate the status, by "pausing" users, like "modal" form, i.e the background gets darkened, and the progress is shown to the user. I have already made the progress bar.

Comment: So... your specific question is how to figure out the status of the background task? Or how to throw up a modal dialog?

Comment: @deceze: to figure out the status in the form of a progress bar..

Comment: Sorry, that's terribly vague. There are two parts to this: Figure out how far the task has progressed, and then display that value as a progress bar. Is there a way you can "ask" your task how far it has progressed?

Comment: I'll try to do that based on the average time for each phase, i.e. starting, executing and so on... My only problem is how am i to make it popup, i mean hide the progress bar, and suddenly bring it to the foreground, making the user wait until it completes.

Comment: @deceze: I'll try to do that based on the average time for each phase, i.e. starting, executing and so on... My only problem is how am i to make it popup, i mean hide the progress bar, and suddenly bring it to the foreground, making the user wait until it completes.

Answer (score 0):

As I feel for the scheduling task go for the windows service rather than go for the schedular in your application. by this way you can easily manage the things and you can also poll satus for your user without freezing your hosted web site.

check this will help you

[Combine Web and Windows Services to Run Your ASP.NET Code at Scheduled Intervals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx)

Comment: I am using the scheduler of Windows. I need the second part

Comment: @Kut - check the article will give info you want

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier if you know the event happens at an exact time.  Otherwise, you'd need to poll the server periodically to see if said task was running.

But if you know it happens at an exact time, I would pass a variable from a server-side scripting language that contains the server time to JavaScript (as you can't rely on the the client-side clock).

Then you calculate the amount of time until the next time the task execution occurs, and use `setTimeout()` to trigger a function that will obscure the website content and overlay a jQuery UI progress bar.

Finally, you then begin to poll to server every so often to check the progress of the task, updating the progress bar as needed.

I think if I were to get into the nitty gritty specifics, my answer would span at least a few questions, so I hope a broad overview is helpful.

**ADDENDUM**

By "span at least a few questions", I mean that your question should really be separated into multiple questions.  1) How do I "pause" users on a website when a task occurs, 2) How do I obscure the website's content with an overlay, and 3) How do I use the jQuery UI progress bar widget.

As to how to obsure the content... if you don't need to worry about mobile clients (i.e., clients that don't support `position: fixed`, you just need to do something like:

```
$('<div id="overlay" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: #000;"></div>')
    .css("opacity", 0.5).appendTo("body");
```

Then you'd position the progress bar widget on top of the overlay.

Comment: ur answer sounds ok.. COuld u pls b a little more elaborate. my task is: "starting", "executing", "ending", I have already designed the progress bar. also, these tasks should be shown in the progress bar.

Comment: especially how to obscure content and 'span at least a few questions'